# interfacing multiple gps

Tags: qgis, gps

I am trying to interface NMEA output of multiple GPS units transmitting wirelessly to a single PC, each GPS position can then be shown on georefance map of that area.

My question

1.) How to interface multiple GPS data with one PC, since one GPS is interfaced automatically in QGIS?

2.) How to display each GPS position simultanously on one map?

Thanks

Comment: are you happy to do a bit of Python code.

Answer (score 2):

Bit complicated I guess;

GPS need a RS232 port and most of the PC's/Notebook come with only one.

Assuming you are using bluetooth GPS to transmit your GPS to PC, then you need to configure multiple virtual ports to handle this. So, you have many GPS receivers ready for handshake.

QGIS at the moment can handshake with one GPS port only. So, you need to modify QGIS to handshake muntiple GPS ports (com1,com2, com3,...).

For those who have one GPS but want to use many applications, like QGIS, Global Mapper etc at the same time with the same GPS, you need to get a [serial port splitter](http://www.fabulatech.com/serial-port-splitter.html) and you can find many others by google search.

Comment: The limitation in only having one GPS active is only in the UI.  Using some Python code you can open more then one port connection.